# arranage array from highest to lowest value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to arrange an array from highest to lowest in a function

i have used array.sort but was informed that that was not allowed for my exerccise

```
function minmax(array){
  var ar = array.sort().join();//I cant use array.join methood
  return ar
}
```

Please help out

Comment: you should include an example of the array to make it easier to point out where the problem lies

Comment: See this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/#Basic

Comment: @Emeeus could you please give the specific link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to implement any of the popular sorting algorithms, but make the comparison used prioritize larger numbers. One example is [this link](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-7.php), the code of which only needs a `>` flipped to a `<`.

Note that if this is a homework or school excercise, copying from anywhere is plagiarism and is generally discouraged.